# How to rotate an object 120deg on every click with CSS-transition/transform throu JS

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to rotate my blueRect 120 deg from its place everytime you push the button, I cant get it to work doh, anyone that can se whats wrong in my code? I know I havent got all the prefixes.  jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a0mycee7/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #blueRect{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #aaaaff;
        border: solid 3px #000000;
        margin-left: 30px;
        transition: all 2s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var angle = 0;

   $('#right').click(function() {
       //$(this).toggleClass('active');
       angle+=120;
        $('#blueRect').css ({
            'transform: rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
               '-moz-transform: rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
                 '-o-transform: rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
                '-ms-transform: rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="background">

    <div id="blueRect">
    </div>

</div>

<button id="right">1</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle for your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a0mycee7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument passed to [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) was not a valid object. The following code should work:

(jQuery was not loaded in the fiddle, and is also needed :) )

```
var angle = 0;
$('#right').click(function() {
   //$(this).toggleClass('active');
   angle+=120;
    $('#blueRect').css ({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
           '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
             '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
});
```

Comment: It dosen't work =/. Maybe there is something wrong with the jQuery link.. Gonna check if its better when I have the file instead. I never use jsfiddle so I didnt know exactly how to do it there :P hehe. Someone else had a jQuery code in it and it worked, strangley. ^^

Comment: I downloaded jQuery instead.. no difrence =/

Comment: wierd, it workes in jsfiddle but not on my computer.. dont know whats the problem.

Comment: It works now, the problem was just stupid of me, I put it all in $(document).ready(function(){}); and now it works! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `.css()` function expects a hash and not an array: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0mycee7/1/)

Basically, change

```
$('#blueRect').css ({
        'transform: rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
           '-moz-transform: rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
             '-o-transform: rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform: rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
```

to

```
$('#blueRect').css ({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
           '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
             '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
```

This throws an error BTW as your initial code had curly brackets (`{}`) but should really have had square brackets (`[]`) as it didn't contain key value pairs. Next time make good use of the JS console in your browser (or FireBug when using Firefox).

Comment: I already tried that and changed it because I thought it didnt mather. I copy, pased and it dosen't work now either =/. And I Checked the console now and it dosen't say anything.

Comment: I put in the hole site in the jsfiddle and it works.. but not for me localy

Comment: It works now, the problem was just stupid of me, I put it all in $(document).ready(function(){}); and now it works! Thank you for your help!